# How to create a table with similiar data the RIGHT way?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I'm trying to make a program that will ping a few server and services wheter they are online or not and *wrote it to Database*. So upon making I was just wondering which is the best way to make it, I would most likely require this three items, but there will be times where I don't.

Here's my current Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE webservice_historylog (
    id_webServiceConnection BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_Location varchar,
    datetime_Connect datetime,
    response_TimeMs int,
    status_Code varchar(5),
    status_Message varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE internet_historylog (
        id_internetConnection BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        id_Location varchar,
        datetime_Connect datetime,
        response_TimeMs int,
        status_Code varchar(5),
        status_Message varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE postgresql_historylog (
        id_postgresqlConnection BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        id_Location varchar,
        datetime_Connect datetime,
        response_TimeMs int,
        status_Code varchar(5),
        status_Message varchar(255)
);
```

I can make a *view table* out of it I guess..

Or should I make it under one table? Like this..

```
CREATE TABLE connection_historylog (
            id_Connection BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            id_Location varchar,
            connectionType varchar, # Internet, WebService, Databases
            datetime_Connect datetime,
            response_TimeMs int,
            status_Code varchar(5),
            status_Message varchar(255)
);
```

**What I wanted:**

Improved in performance for longer term goals, cause it's actively writing like every one minute. This would also affect how I will call this data later on. More info can be asked.

Comment: Why is `time_Connect` of type `date`? Why not have a single column of type `datetime` or `timestamp` to contain both the date and time?

Comment: Oh sorry, will fix that.. And why not `datetime`? I've read somewhere it's better to use `date` and `time` separately.. But I'm not quite sure myself, since I'm new to Databases, but if it turns out to be wrong, then please correct me.

Comment: This is a false statement. Use a *datetime* or a *timestamp* format and do not separate date and time. If you separate them it will complexify your future queries and add stress to your database for nothing. *Date* and *Time* format should only be used if you only have to store a date or a time, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Ah ok, after damien_the_unbeliever comment about it, I started to look again for it. Question updated. Also thanks to @ThomasG for the enlightenment!

Comment: Your current schema works only if your are certain that you wont add a lot of "connection types" in the future, which would force you to create additional tables and write new code. Personally I would go for the second option :Putting all logs in the same table with a type column.

Comment: Are there anything else I need to note? You can write an answer, so anyone can vote it up or ask there.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should put similar table in a single table.  This has multiple advantages over time:

- Queries that look at different types of data are much simpler -- and easier to optimize.
- You can add new types just by, well, inserting into an existing table.
- Maintenance and operations are simpler.  Adding an index, for instance, only needs to happen on one table rather than multiple tables.
- In an insert-only environment, the tables will have filled data pages, which is better for performance.

To make such an environment work best, you'll want indexes and perhaps partitioning.  The specific indexes depend on how the data will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Single table, but primarily because that is probably the 'right' way.

Other notes:

- Performance of writes will be the same either way.
- One `INSERT` per minute is trivial.  Even 1/second is trivial.  1000/second can get dicey.
- Performance of reads depends on what filtering/sorting you will be doing.  Once we see the `SELECTs`, we can discuss `INDEXes`.
- 1 row/minute is less than a million rows/year, so I don't think anything needs discussing about scaling.
- Nothing (yet) indicates that `PARTITIONing` would be of any use.